# Is the amount of memory displayed in the Android profiler the same as what getTotalPss() of the Debug.MemoryInfo class returns at a specific instance?

Tags: android, profiling, memory-profiling, android-profiler

I am using `Debug.MemoryInfo` class to log the various statistics about the memory mappings for a process.
Here is the implementation:

```
Debug.MemoryInfo appMemoryInfo = new Debug.MemoryInfo();
Debug.getMemoryInfo(appMemoryInfo);
Log.i("MemoryInfo", "Memory map: " + appMemoryInfo.getMemoryStats());
Log.i("MemoryInfo", "Total PSS: " + appMemoryInfo.getTotalPss()/1024 + " MB" );
```

Does the output of the `appMemoryInfo.getTotalPss()/1024` at an instance equals the total shown in the android profiler?